# Pay As You Go subcriptiona cancellation in Azure

Tags: azure

I just created a azure account. When I see my subcription it shows two

1. 3 Months Free Trial
2. Pay-As-You-Go

I want only the trial thing at the moment. So I cancelled Pay-As-You-Go. (It's status is currently Disabled)
So I just want to know that will I be charged for this. Or should I remove this by contacting suppor center to be safe.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not deploy anything to your Pay-As-You-Go subscription then you should not get billed for it.  Since it is disabled then you shouldn't be able to deploy anything to it, or use it anyway, so you should be safe.  You may get billed for anything that was used by that subscription prior to it being disabled (if you used it for something).

I believe you can call support and request they remove the subscription completely if you like.  I had an old beta subscription linked to my ID that was disabled and contacting support is what got it removed.